# split string each x characters in dataframe

Tags: r, string, split, character

I know there are some answers here about splitting a string every `nth` character, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208490/split-each-character-in-r) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497583/split-a-string-every-5-characters),  However these are pretty question specific and mostly related to a single string and not to a data frame of multiple strings.

---

**Example data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:2, seq = c('ABCDEFGHI', 'ZABCDJHIA'))
```

Looks like this:

```
  id       seq
1  1 ABCDEFGHI
2  2 ZABCDJHIA
```

**Splitting on every third character**

I want to split the string in each row every thrid character, such that the resulting data frame looks like this:

```
id  1   2   3
1   ABC DEF GHI
2   ZAB CDJ HIA
```

**What I tried**

I used the `splitstackshape` before to split a string on a single character, like so: `df %>% cSplit('seq', sep = '', stripWhite = FALSE, type.convert = FALSE)` I would love to have a similar function (or perhaps it is possbile with cSplit) to split on every third character.

Comment: Related: [Chopping a string into a vector of fixed width character elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247045/chopping-a-string-into-a-vector-of-fixed-width-character-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    separate(seq, into = paste0("x", 1:3), sep = c(3, 6))
# id  x1  x2  x3
#1  1 ABC DEF GHI
#2  2 ZAB CDJ HIA
```

If we want to create it more generic

```
n1 <- nchar(as.character(df$seq[1])) - 3
s1 <- seq(3, n1, by = 3)
nm1 <- paste0("x", seq_len(length(s1) +1))
df %>% 
    separate(seq, into = nm1, sep = s1)
```

---

Or using `base R`, using `strsplit`, split the 'seq' column for each instance of 3 characters by passing a regex lookaround into a `list` and then `rbind` the `list` elements

```
df[paste0("x", 1:3)] <- do.call(rbind, 
           strsplit(as.character(df$seq), "(?<=.{3})", perl = TRUE))
```

NOTE: It is better to avoid column names that start with non-standard labels such as numbers.  For that reason, appended 'x' at the beginning of the names

Comment: Okay that's smart ;) thankyou! much clearer than the other answers I have read so far

Comment: How can the tidyverse one be made more generic, because now I have to provide both the column names as well as the split points

Comment: @CodeNoob You can use `seq` to create the split points i.e. `seq(3,  nchar(seq)-3, by = 3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can *split a string each x characters* in *base* also with [read.fwf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.0/topics/read.fwf) *(Read Fixed Width Format Files)*, which needs either a file or a [connection](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/textConnection).

```
read.fwf(file=textConnection(as.character(df$seq)), widths=c(3,3,3))

   V1  V2  V3
1 ABC DEF GHI
2 ZAB CDJ HIA
```